# Why double free or corruption error in C? I freed my mallocs

Tags: c, string, memory-management, malloc, free

I am getting this error:

> Error in `./sorter': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000685010

and then a bunch of numbers which is the memory map.
My program reads a CSV file of movies and their attributes from stdin and tokenizes it. The titles of the movies with commas in them are surrounded in quotes, so I split each line into 3 tokens and tokenize the front and back token again using the comma as the delimeter. I free all my mallocs at the end of the code but I still get this error. The csv is scanned until the end but I get an the error message. If I don't free the mallocs at all I don't get an error message but I highly doubt it is right. This is my main() :

```
char* CSV = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*500);
char* fronttoken = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*500);
char* token = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*500);
char* backtoken = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*500);
char* title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
while(fgets(CSV, sizeof(CSV)*500,stdin))
{   
    fronttoken = strtok(CSV, "\"");     //store token until first quote, if no quote, store whole line
    title = strtok(NULL,"\"");          //store token after first quote until 2nd quote
    if(title != NULL)                   //if quotes in line, consume comma meant to delim title
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");      //eat comma
    }
    backtoken = strtok(NULL,"\n");  //tokenize from second quote to \n character (remainder of line)

    printf("Front : %s\nTitle: %s\nBack: %s\n", fronttoken, title, backtoken);  //temp print statement to see front,back,title components

    token = strtok(fronttoken, ",");    //tokenizing front using comma delim
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    if (title != NULL)      //print if there is a title with comma
    {
        printf("%s\n",title);
    }   
    token = strtok(backtoken,",");  //tokenizing back using comma delim
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}

free(CSV);
free(token);    
free(fronttoken);
free(backtoken);
free(title);

return 0;
```

Comment: `while(fgets(CSV, sizeof(CSV)*500,stdin))` --> `while(fgets(CSV, sizeof(*CSV)*500,stdin))`

Comment: `strtok` doesn't allocate memory, you shouldn't free all the pointers returned by it.

Comment: In addition to what @Jack said, the memory you created with `malloc` is leaked once you assign the output of `strtok` to the pointer, since you no longer have a pointer to it to free it.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: You have sizeof on the brain... `char *CSV = malloc(500); fgets(CSV, 500, stdin);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus here:

```
char* title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
title = strtok(NULL,"\"");
```

1. You dynamically allocate memory that `title` points to.
2. You assign the return value of `strtok` to `title`, losing any
   reference to the memory dynamically allocated with `malloc()`! This
   means that you will definetely have a memory leak, since you will
   never be able to de-allocate the memory you dynamically allocated
   before.

The ref's example of [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) has a very informative example:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As a result, there is no need to allocate memory for what `strtok()` returns - it's actually bad as I explained before.

Back to your code:

```
free(title);
```

does nothing, since `title` is `NULL` at that point (because of the while loop after `strtok()`.

Same with `token`.

---

Furthermore, `fronttoken` and `backtoken` also result in memory leaks, since they are assigned the return value of `strtok()`, after `malloc()` has been called. But their `free()` is problematic too (in contrast with the other de-allocations of `title` and `token`), since they point within the original memory allocated for `CSV`.

So, when `free(backtoken);` is called, double-free or memory corruption occurs.

---

Moreover, change this:

```
while(fgets(CSV, sizeof(CSV)*500,stdin))
```

to this:

```
while(fgets(CSV, sizeof(*CSV)*500,stdin))
```

since you want the size of where `CSV` points to (that's the size of the memory you dynamically allocated).

Comment: `free` of `fronttoken` and `backtoken` are also problematic as they point somewhere within the original memory allocated for `CSV` leading to the double-free or corruption when `free(backtoken)` is called.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still a beginner at C and don't know when to use the malloc on pointers. So I should only use malloc when making an array? Just making a char* pointer is the same as making a string in java and can be changed? I'm still confused but hopefully I will learn eventually.

Comment: @codemonkey you are welcome. You should dynamically allocate memory only when you have to. Check the example of `strtok()` and study about pointers. BTW, if the answer helped you, please *accept* it by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer.